# Why is Next.js throwing Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props even though component has "use client" on top?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

My bundler creates a simple React component as follows

```
"use client";
"use strict";var a=Object.create;var r=Object.defineProperty;var b=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;var i=Object.getOwnPropertyNames;var l=Object.getPrototypeOf,s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;var m=(t,o)=>{for(var n in o)r(t,n,{get:o[n],enumerable:!0})},c=(t,o,n,u)=>{if(o&&typeof o=="object"||typeof o=="function")for(let e of i(o))!s.call(t,e)&&e!==n&&r(t,e,{get:()=>o[e],enumerable:!(u=b(o,e))||u.enumerable});return t};var B=(t,o,n)=>(n=t!=null?a(l(t)):{},c(o||!t||!t.__esModule?r(n,"default",{value:t,enumerable:!0}):n,t)),f=t=>c(r({},"__esModule",{value:!0}),t);var x={};m(x,{Button:()=>k});module.exports=f(x);var p=B(require("react")),k=()=>p.createElement("button",{onClick:()=>alert("boop")},"Boop");0&&(module.exports={Button});
//# sourceMappingURL=Button.js.map
```

Although it has "use client" on top, Next.js throws error `Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props. {onClick: function, children: "Boop"}`

Components actual code as requested in comments

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";

export const Button = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => alert("boop")}>Boop</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate the error by manually copying your component code in a dummy package inside `node_modules` folder. I noticed that when I add `"use client"` on top of the index.js file that imports and exports this component, then it works just fine. I don't know why it worked this way, but it solves the issue well.

Have your exports like this

```
- your-package
  - index.js
  - Button
    - Button.js
    - index.js <- add "use client" on top of this file. (this file will import and export the Button)
```

Works only when you import like `import {Button} from "your-package/Button"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked by keeping the default export explicit.

So, for you, it should be:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";

const Button = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => alert("boop")}>Boop</button>;
};
export default Button;
```